# Service fabric and WCF

Tags: wcf, azure-service-fabric, etw

We are planning to redesign our services to micro services using service fabric, I have some questions that I hope you can help me with, here we go:

**Communication Stack**
All our services are on WCF using net.tcp so in theory we can reuse the  WCF Communication stack but I'm not sure that's the best way, what are the differences between the default communication stack and the WCF one?

**Extensibility**
We have a lot of implementation using the extensibility points of WCF, if we choose the WCF communication stack can we still use this? We are basically using `IServiceBehavior`,`IOperationInvoker`, `OperationContext` and `ServiceSecurityContext` for this:

**1. Security** `ServiceSecurityContext`/`OperationContext` to get the IP and if the call is in the intranet the domain account who is making the call, I checked in StatelessServiceContext but could not find any property where i could get this info.

**2. Parameters and time** `IOperationInvoker` to log the parameters of the method and how much it took to finish the operation, reading [this](https://www.azureserviceprofiler.com/help/custom-instrumentation) it appears that if implement the Start/Stop methods the time duration is done automatically, what I'm not sure is if this will work in the context of an attribute and with `IErrorHandler` when an error happens.

**3. Notifications** `IErrorHandler` to log the exception and then send an email to the developer team, we are currently doing this using an SMTP server, is there a better way to send notifications in azure?.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Answering this:

**Communication Stack**
Never did a comparison in performance between the default listener and WcfCommunicationListener but we opted for WCF to reuse all our components and as a first version to understand how service fabric works.

**Extensibility**

1. **Security** All the code worked the same, we needed to make some changes to the way the context works, but all the info needed was there (plus some data on the node it was running)
2. **Parameters and time** We used Azure Service Profiler with our own implementation of Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource capturing the data  using IOperationInvoker, awesome
3. **Notifications** IErrorHandler continued to work but we used sendgrid for the emails.